# x86 syscalls access violation writing location

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I'm working on a small project aiming to grab syscall ids from ntdlls exports then doing some shenanigans to map the arguments properly to call it. It seems I'm doing everything correctly however I'm getting an unhandled exception in my asm.

source code:

```
    mov    edx , ecx
    pop    ecx
    pop    eax
    mov    DWORD PTR [esp] , ecx ;  Access violation writing location 0x0000F8B8.
    mov    eax , DWORD PTR [esp+18h]
```

code from disassembly:

```
 mov         dx,cx  
 pop         cx  
 pop         ax  
 mov         word ptr [si],cx ;  Access violation writing location 0x0000F8B8.
 and         al,67h  
 mov         ax,word ptr [esp+18h]
```

```
EAX = 00007B00 EBX = 00000000 ECX = 001F59F5 EDX = 43D2FFFF ESI = 43D2F8B8 
EDI = 43D2F450 EIP = 7B010CAD ESP = 43D2F33C EBP = 43D2F450 EFL = 00010246
```

Comment: If that's really where the error happens that means you have already trashed `esp`. The problem is elsewhere in earlier code.

Comment: Yeah, [esp] should definitely be accessible. 0x0000F9A8 is generally way too low of an address for the stack pointer. I think you stuck a heap pointer or other incorrect value in esp before.

Comment: Prior to that, I'm just mapping arguments around and calling the asm stub.

Comment: Asm stub? What does it do and how do you call it? What does mapping arguments around entail?

Comment: Try single-stepping with a debugger. You can also try watching esp and maybe setting up a breakpoint for when esp goes under 0x10000000 so you can see where it gets trashed.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 I updated the post to reflect everything I've gathered.

Comment: That disassembly seems to be 16 bit. Also you claim `ESP = 3C2DEED4` in which case _"Access violation writing location 0x0000F9A8"_ clearly can't refer to the `mov DWORD PTR [esp], ecx`.

Comment: Yeah, that's 16-bit disassembly. You're not accessing [esi], you're accessing [si], which takes only the bottom two bytes of esi and zeros everything else.

Comment: I'm aware however the source code is not 16bit...

Comment: But even that isn't `F9A8`. I assume the disassembly was made in the wrong mode (would be quite difficult to execute 16 bit code in windows).

Comment: It doesn't need to be in 16-bit mode, I think these are valid instructions in 32-bit mode also, but have operand sizes of 16-bit...

Comment: But `SI=EED4` so that doesn't match the address in the error either.

Comment: It's possible he mistakenly put the register output for a different stage in the execution. Or that the register values were changed by the error handler or debugger.

Comment: Yes, I updates the post sorry.

Comment: Yeah, now it matches. So that means you assembled the code wrong. I think you assembled the 32 bit code for 16 bit which when executed in 32 bit mode will revert everything back to 16 bit.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, your disassembly appears to have 16-bit instructions (using 16-bit registers like cx, ax, etc.) The offending instruction accesses memory at [si]. The value of si is the bottom 2 bytes of esi, which would lead to a sub-0x10000 value like 0x0000F9A8. Truncating off the top half of the address is probably what caused the error. I'm not sure what you're using to assemble, but try checking its command line options to make sure you haven't set a 16-bit flag or something.